# Why there is no .git folder genereted on cloning repository?

Tags: git, github

I am currently trying to learn Git and Github and I am following this tutorial on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RGOj5yH7evk&t=1525s

I simply try to clone a demo repository:

```
 git clone git@github.com:hshtg1/demo-repo.git
```

but the .git folder isn't generated in the local directory folder. I have the option to show hidden files checked.

Also, I've tried to use:

```
git init
```

but when trying `git add .` this results in a message like this:

```
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:
hint:
hint:   git submodule add <url> demo-repo
hint:
hint: If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the
hint: index with:
hint:
hint:   git rm --cached demo-repo
hint:
hint: See "git help submodule" for more information.
```

Then I `git commit -m "message"` and try to `git push origin main` (not master) and receive this error:

```
error: src refspec main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'origin'
```

I've also tried `git remote add origin ssh://login@IP/path/to/repository` and redoing the whole thing, but I still cannot make it work properly.

Comment: If you've cloned a repo (see VonC's excellent answer below), then you don't also need to do `git init`. `git init` is for brand-new repos that don't exist anyplace else; `git clone` is for bringing in repos that do exist elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

> but the .git folder isn't generated in the local directory folder

Such a git clone command would create a `demo-repo` folder, in which you would find the `.git` hidden subfolder.

Check your environment variables for any `GIT_...` (a `GIT_DIR`, for instance, might mean a different location for the `.git` folder), but beside that, git clone create the folder and the `.git`.